# What's the proper way to get this information?

Tags: php

So I'm a php newbie creating my very first android application. I'm using the volley library to pass parameters to php and json, but I can't get this php script to work (I've been testing it with Postman since I didn't start this activity just yet.)

```
<?php 
    require_once 'connection.php';
    header('Content-Type: application/json ');

    class produtos {
        private $db;
        private $connection;

        function __construct(){
            $this->db = new DB_Connection();
            $this->connection = $this->db->get_connection();            
        } //__construct

        function returnProducts($parameter) {   
            if ($parameter != 'Todos')      
                $query = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE pdstatus = '$parameter'";
                else if ($parameter == 'Todos')
                $query = "SELECT * FROM produtos";
            $result = mysqli_query($this->connection,$query);

            if (!mysqli_num_rows($result))
                echo json_encode("Nenhum resultado encontrado.");
            else {
                while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ //transforma em array os resultados da query
                    $data[] = $res;         
                } //while
                echo json_encode(array("products"=>$data));
            } //else
        } //function
    } //produtos

    $product = new Produtos();
    $parameter = array("status"=>$_POST['pdstatus']);
    $product -> returnProducts($parameter);
?>
```

I realize what's wrong with it (trying to use $parameter on my SELECT query), but I just don't know how to fix it. Have tried a few methods to access this variable and it didn't work... Pls help!

Comment: the proper way is parameter binning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use $name_of_array['value'] to access to a array value. Use this:

```
if ($parameter["status"] !== 'Todos')      
    $query = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE pdstatus = '".$parameter['status']."'";
```

And in all the places that $parameter exists do the same.

Comment: ohh so that's what happenned there... Thanks, that worked!